# make a vbs script ever running in windows?

Tags: vbscript, windows-scripting

I have a vb script (say myScript.vbs) which is used to monitor a file size (say A file) and trigger mail if it hits threshold size. I made this scipt to run on my computer.

But problem in this is, if the restart or log off and log in again, this script is not running behind.

How to make this script ever running, is it possible to add this script in Start up of windows??

Comment: Super User has the answer: http://superuser.com/questions/15596/automatically-run-a-script-when-i-log-on-to-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the script in **Startup** folder of Windows :)

Comment: Thanks Sarfraz. I'm trying on that. will add up comment again in few mins